How to mock an external library in tests (httplib::Client )
Generally when writing unit tests, we create classes from interfaces and create mock classes for tests. e.g.
class TestedClass {

   TestedClass(std::shared_ptr<IDependency> dependency_ptr){...}

}

So it is easy to mock the dependency here by just inheriting from IDependency, like:
class MockDependency: public IDependency {
...
}

But how do we follow that approach for third party libraries? In this particular case, I am using httplib::Client. Since it is a concrete class from a thirdparty vendor, how can I mock that to test my own class which uses this class (injected via dependency injection)?

It looks like the XY problem. Why do you need to test httplib::Client? Should not you test your code?

I am not testing httplib::Client. I am testing my own class which uses httplib::Client

I do not understand problem. Just create interface which will hide httplib::Client API and then just mock it.

Alright, that's the obvious approach but it is a lot of repeated work (wrapping all the methods). Any better approach?

It is lots of work if you use lots of functionalities from that library. Just mock things you need.

You normally don't want to integrate external library into your code as is. If you ever need to update the library to non-backwards compatible version or to change the library, you need to modify your entire codebase. Instead, create an API of your own to fulfil your needs, and implement that API using a library. This way you are back to your simple case of IDependency and your code is no longer deeply coupled with an external library.

I doubt you are using every method httplib::Client can offer, so try to design your own interface that is enough for your application, e.g.:
class IHttpClient {
public:
    virtual ~IHttpClient() = default;
    virtual std::string get(std::string url) = 0;
    // more interfaces
};

Then your production implementation can be e.g. like this:
    std::string get(std::string url) override {
        httplib::Client cli(url);
        auto res = cli.Get("/hi");
        // error handling, maybe throw something
        return res->body;
    }

and in the tests you can have
ON_CALL(mockClient, get(matchingUrl)).WillByDefault(Return("expected reply"));

